# How to create a product list from an e-commerce site?

Tags: algorithm, text

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask, but here I go.

I want to create a generic product ist from an ecommerce site. For example if I have this:

```
Acer Aspire X 4GB RAM ---- $400
Acer Aspire X 4GB RAM ---- $410
Acer Aspire X 4GB RAM ---- $420
Acer Aspire X 2GB RAM ---- $350
Apple macbook X 8GB RAM ---- $1400
Apple macbook X 6GB RAM ---- $1200
Apple macbook X 6GB RAM ---- $1220            (notice that some products can be repeated here)
```

I need to get thiss by clasifying the info:

```
1- Acer Aspire X 4GB
2- Acer Aspire X 2GB 
3- Acer macbook 8GB 
4- Acer macbook 6GB
```

So, what kind of technique should I use??

Thank you in advance!!

right now im using php, but I think it could be written in any langauge.

Comment: I've changed the tags to better match the question. You might get a better response if you specified the programming language you intend to use.

Comment: and also what ecommerce site you're talking about.  it's impossible to write something for any ecommerce system.  that's google shopping.

Comment: sorry I dont mean to access the data, but the method, maybe ia, to classify the information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well if you are using PHP you could try to use and enhance function I have used. It is not very advanced and there will be also a better approach. E.g. this function compares word by word but you also could compare letter by letter. If you have very large amount of products then you might have a problem because you need to compare all of them against each others. However best and fastest way might be to use SQL and maybe Fulltext-search.

PHP-Code:

```
function getSimilarStart($s1, $s2) {
    $split1 = explode(' ', $s1);
    $split2 = explode(' ', $s2);

    $starta = array();
    $start = '';
    foreach ($split1 as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($split2[$k]) && $v == $split2[$k] && $start == substr($s2, 0, strlen($start))) {
            $starta[] = $v;
            $start = join (' ', $starta);
        } else {
            return $start;
        }
    }

    return $start;   
}
```

Comment: Should i delete my answer? I still get negative votes without any comments. This is annoying. Please comment something and please understand this was answered 3 and half years ago.